# Win 10 not detecting mouse movement from Python code

Tags: python, python-3.x

I've written a small program that will move the cursor every 5 seconds if it has not been moved.
I've provided the code below.
But it seems that no matter how much I move it, Windows 10 does not recognise it's movement.
To speed up the testing, I've set Turn Off display to 1 min in the Power plan settings. When this code it run through the CMD, I can see the mouse moving back and forward, but the screen still goes to sleep after 1 min.
Is there something I'm missing here?
Thank you

```
#! python3
import pyautogui as p
import time as t
# CTRL+C to stop it
p.FAILSAFE = False
try:
    while True:
        # get current mouse position
        x1,y1 = p.position()
        positionStr1 = 'X: ' + str(x1).rjust(4) + ' Y: ' + str(y1).rjust(4)
        print("check1")
    
    print(positionStr1, end='')
    print("\n")
    
    # wait 5 sec
    t.sleep(5)
    #check the position again
    x2,y2 = p.position()
    positionStr2 = 'X: ' + str(x2).rjust(4) + ' Y: ' + str(y2).rjust(4)
    print("check2")
    print(positionStr2, end='')
    print("\n")
    
    if positionStr1 == positionStr2:
        p.moveRel(200,0, duration=.1)
        p.moveRel(-200,0,duration=.1)
        p.moveRel(200,0, duration=.1)
        p.moveRel(-200,0,duration=.1)
    else:
        print('mouse moved')

except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print('\nDone')
```

Comment: Maybe windows power save does not care about cursor movements, but about whether input comes from input devices. You can create a virtual input device and have similar code inject some activity there, maybe that helps. Perhaps there is even a win api to just make the machine not sleep. Also, can't you just set the power plan to not go to sleep?

Comment: it's a work pc, so I can't change the sleep time. I have an Excel macro that does the same thing and it prevents the screen from turning off. What do you mean a virtual input device?